# Unable to convert JArray inside another to list of objects (Automapper - Net Core)

Tags: c#, json, automapper

I need to convert a JSON received in the next format:

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Poland",
          "image_path": "/images/countries/png/short/pl.png",
          "extra": {
            "continent": "Europe",
            "sub_region": "Eastern Europe",
            "world_region": "EMEA",
            "fifa": "POL",
            "iso": "POL",
            "iso2": "PL",
            "longitude": "19.37775993347168",
            "latitude": "52.147850036621094",
            "flag": "............"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "Brazil",
          "image_path": "/images/countries/png/short/br.png",
          "extra": {
            "continent": "Americas",
            "sub_region": "South America",
            "world_region": "AMER",
            "fifa": "BRA",
            "iso": "BRA",
            "iso2": "BR",
            "longitude": "-52.97311782836914",
            "latitude": "-10.81045150756836",
            "flag": "............"
          }
        }]
}
```

to a list of object like this

```
public class Country : BaseModel
{

    public override long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ISO { get; set; }
    public string FIFA { get; set; }
    public string Flag { get; set; }
   
}
```

I've created the CountryProfile:

```
    public class CountryProfile : Profile
{
    public CountryProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<JToken, Country>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Active, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => true))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["id"]))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["name"]))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FIFA, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["extra"]["fifa"].ToString()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ISO, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["extra"]["iso"].ToString()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Flag, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["extra"]["flag"].ToString()));
    }
}
```

And everything works fine but when I added the last three lines of the profile:

```
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FIFA, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["extra"]["fifa"].ToString()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ISO, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["extra"]["iso"].ToString()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Flag, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["extra"]["flag"].ToString()));
```

I receive and error when try to map the JSON using:

```
JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(await client.GetStringAsync(BuildApiCall(apiOptions.ApiV + endpoint)));

return _mapper.Map<JToken, IList<TEntity>>(jobject["data"]);
```

that says:

> Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types:
> JToken -> IList`1 Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken -> System.Collections.Generic.IList`1

I guess the error is coming from the mapping of the items inside src["extra"] but I'm not able to coming up with an answer to that

Comment: Why not just create type hierarchy representing your json, parse to it and then map to needed structure?

Comment: Also can you please add full error text?

Comment: I could create exactly the same hierarchy, but I'd like to know what could be the solution to the error using the class like it is. The exception message is just the text I've put in the question, nothing else

Answer (score 0):

One of the items in the JSON had a value to null and it was generating the error. Controlling the null value was enough to make it works